# Visual Studio Build and Release to Azure Web App - Update Configurations

Tags: asp.net, wcf, azure, web.config-transform, azure-pipelines

I have a web app developed in ASP.NET hosted in Azure Web App through Visual Studio CI Build and Release Management. I also have few environment specific app settings which I use placeholders like `__PLACEHODLER__` and then the environment specific variable is given the respective environment app Azure App Settings. Which is working great, no issues

The issue is, Now I have added WCF end point into the config and needs to change the endpoint & bindings to specific environment (like PROD connects to PROD service and QA connects UAT so on)

I tried giving like

```
<endpoint address="https://__ENDPOINT__/ProfileService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"...
```

But is seems it is not referring the `__ENDPOINT__` value given the azure app settings. SO the bigger question is, Can we have simple mechanism / tool to update the any placeholders in the config file while my build gets deployed?. These values are environment specific, so I cannot have a global value for all.

I had gone through few online forums but seems there is no easy way to update the config file other than app settings while it deploy into Azure through Visual Studio 2015 Build & release management portal.

Please help me if you have any solution out there. Thanks!

Comment: you can have web.config transformations for each environment like web.staging.config, web.prod.config for each build/publish profiles.

Comment: @Aravind, That end up having multiple redundant builds for each environment. I wish not to take up that route. Thanks though\

Comment: only  build profiles will be different. obviously in any CI system you will have separate configs for various environments.